# using git branch to have different paths?

Tags: git

I'm sure I'm not using git correctly.
I have a bunch of scripts that I'm running in my local folder during development. 
But, once I'm done I will need to change the paths on my scripts to a share folder.
I have write access to my local folder but do not have write access to my a global share folder.

With this in mind, I was developing my code in my master branch.
 Then after I'm done, I created a share branch which I then checkout, change paths to the share folder, then commit.
When I need to add new feature, I will then change my codes in master branch. 
 But, this is when I realized I can't apply new feature to share branch without changing the paths.

What is the recommended way to do this in git? To apply new changes but keep different paths. Is it possible? 
Thank you in advance for your help.

Updated with example to hopefully clarify things.
In **master branch**, I have a folder scripts with bash.sh

```
scripts
---bash.sh
```

```
#bash.sh
image_dir=/home/image/
```

In **share branch**, I have the same data structure:

```
scripts
---bash.sh
```

However, the `image_dir` is different:

```
#bash.sh
image_dir=/share/image/
```

As I updated the bash.sh in  **master branch** like this:

```
#bash.sh
image_dir=/home/image/
# this is new code
```

I wanted to apply the `"# this is new code"` to share branch, however, I wanted to maintain the same image_dir that was in share branch.

Comment: To me this question is unclear, can you elaborate? If you have the folder inside of your repo, why don't you have write access to it? Why do you need to rename/move the folder in your branch – why can't you just clone the repo to a different directory and then switch branches? If the files can be detected as "moved" by Git, doesn't a normal `git merge` work to bring the changes from one file to the other?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I've added an example that will hopefully clarify my question.

Comment: I think this is a fine workflow with Git - I sometimes keep "temporary" or "debug" commits in a branch, then `rebase` or `cherry-pick` that branch on top of my "actual" code changes.  However, the fact that you even need to do this in the first place is a bit of a smell.  Have you considered passing `image_dir` as an argument to the script, or as an environment variable?

Comment: It sounds like you are using `git` as a type of deployment tool. I wouldn't recommend doing that. Write a script (which itself can be checked into the repository) that copies your scripts the appropriate shared folder. Things like `image_dir` can be set via environment variables.

Comment: How do you `rebase` or `cherry-pink` to apply `#this is new code` without changing `image_dir`?
The script is only an example. I have a bunch of paths in multiple scripts that I cannot pass as an argument. Plus, I'm trying to make this as easy as possible for other people to run.

Comment: @chepner, you may be right. I'm trying to make it very easy for other people to run. If I set `image_dir` via environment variables, doesn't that require other people that wants to run my code to know where it is?

Comment: @cnyt Maybe you could have one script and pass in a settings file. Then you can have different settings files such as `local.settings` and `shared.settings` that contain all of the possible different paths used by the script. You could track both settings files in Git too. You, and others, simply pass in which settings you want to use. Or, you could have the same settings filename, but it contains different values on the different branches, if you prefer that route.